# Property page for custom Directshow filter

Tags: c++, dll, directshow, base-class, graphedit

I managed to create a custom DirectShow transform filter, register it, and export it in a DLL. It now works properly in both GraphEdit and a C++ test program. My next goal is to create a custom interface to control the filter's main parameter, from a test app or from a property page in GraphEdit.

Following [these instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375010%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), I got my custom interface working properly from the C++ test program. However, I'm facing difficulties with the property page : I keep getting the error message "The requested property page could not be displayed" in GraphEdit.

While debugging, I found that the only methods called (in my custom property page class, derived from CBasePropertyPage) are `OnConnect()` and `OnDisconnect()` - which is oddly (or not ?) called twice. Between these two methods, some calls are made to CBasePropertyPage methods (file cprop.cpp in baseclasses), and everything looks fine until :

`STDMETHODIMP CBasePropertyPage::Activate(HWND hwndParent, LPCRECT pRect, BOOL fModal)`

and more precisely

`m_hwnd = CreateDialogParam(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(m_DialogId), hwndParent, DialogProc, (LPARAM) this);`

I always get `m_hwnd` at 0, causing the method to return with an error. I tried to add `GetLastError()` right after this instruction, but it always returns 0, no error. Moreover, every parameter of `CreateDialogParam()` looks properly initialized...

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

**EDIT** :

For now, in order to at least have a working example, I've used the *same* resources/templates described in the [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375010%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

**---EDIT 2---** :

While debugging a little bit more, I tried deleting every single control (button, scroller) from the Dialog resource. After that... everything works. `CreateDialogParam()` returns a correct value, my class's `OnActivate()` is called and so on. I eventually get a "filter properties" page in GraphEdit, but empty (except from the default dialog window).

But as soon as I had a control, e.g. a MF command button, the previous problems appear.

Is there any kind of incompatibility between DirectShow base classes and the controls I use ? (And if so, why isn't the provided sample mentioning anything ?) Is there any simpler way to add controls to the property page ?

(I'm definitely *not* an expert with GUIs and Win32 controls...)

Comment: with MF command button you mean MFC? Then AfxWinInit is probably not called (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w04bs753%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). I would suggest not to use MFC controls.

Comment: Sorry - I actually meant "Microsoft Forms" templates (CommandButton & so on), in the proposed list of ActiveX controls when creating a dialog resource. Maybe it's the same thing, but I'm not sure. How could I create a proper property page without MFC controls ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: In addition to Wimmel's comment: check out http://blog.monogram.sk/janos/2008/01/10/directshow-baseclasses-and-mfc/ for how to use MFC with DS filters. Otherwise stick to plain old Win32 controls on your property page.

Comment: I just found a way to include plain simple Win32 controls in a Formview that I'll use as the PropertyPage. Looks okay for now - I'll keep you posted. I'll try using MFC later, though. Thanks :)

Comment: Just finished what I needed to do, using basic Win32 controls (buttons & edits) in a "FormView" resource. Everything works fine. I'll try using MFC in a future project. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BlueCookie, can you post that as an answer, so that can be accepted to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem came from the way I was creating the controls for the Property Page. I use a simple "Formview" resource, but I was trying to add the controls through the graphical resource viewer (or whatever you want to call it) : right click, "Insert ActiveX Control..." and using "Microsoft Form 2.0".

Using a Formview resource with plain old Win32 controls (initialized with `CreateWindowEx()` and managed with a classic message loop), everything went ok.

Thanks a lot for your help !